# SQLAlchemy not recognizing db.Model

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to set up sqlalchemy with just a python script. 
Here is the output:

```
NameError: name 'db' is not defined
```

I am aware that this may be a noobie request.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


class newsPosts(db.Model):

    newsSite = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)

def main():

    # Set up DB

    engine = \
        create_engine('sqlite:////Users/Desktop/practice/database.db'
                      )

    db = SQLAlchemy(engine)

    # REST OF CODE #

    print("hello world")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `db` variable before you use it

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


engine = create_engine('sqlite:////Users/Desktop/practice/database.db')
db = SQLAlchemy(engine)


class newsPosts(db.Model):

    newsSite = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)


def main():
    print("hello world")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```